# Duda con FOR y IF en javascript para más objetos en un array

Tags: javascript, if, bucle-for

Tengo este JS que me devuelve el texto de un elemento desde el breadcrumb:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('brdcramb')[0].children[1].innerText;
```

Ahora bien, estoy ocurre cuando el breadcrumb es:

Inicio > Elemento1

Si tengo que realizar una concatenación de más elementos, tipo:

Inicio > Elemento1 > SubElemento2

Y me recoge los dos últimos tenía pensado:

1. Ver `IF children.lenght` es mayor de 1 `ELSE` me devuelve el valor.
2. A través de `FOR ... WHILE`, creo que me he atascado en este paso por
   el hecho de decir `children[i] donde i > 1`, y luego construir el
   todo.

¿Es correcto o es preferible crear varios IFs ?

Gracias

Comment: Buenas, pero **¿Cuál es el problema?, ¿Qué has intentado?**, la pregunta es de baja calidad para este sitio web, pon ejemplo del código que tienes, para qué se usa, que tienes al principio y qué valor deseas obtener, etc. Edita tu pregunta para poder responder adecuadamente y resolver tu duda, si no podemos estar respondiendote a algo que no es lo que buscas... De todas formas, la solución a la duda que parece que planteas? ni bucles ni concatenar un if en otro, crea una función recursiva. Mira [como elaborar una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola @MarcusRB, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hola MarcusRB, necesitamos ver el código HTML para saber si el código que compartes es correcto o por qué falla (preferiblemente como un snippet directamente en la pregunta donde ver el error). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información sobre cómo hacer esto.

Answer (score 0):

aquí os mando un extracto de la consola. Lo que estoy realizando es una JavaScript desde GTM.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los objetos, 0 1 2 se refieren a esto breadcrumb

**Inicio > Gaming y Consolas > Sillas Gaming**

La idea es crear esta misma estructura desde JavaScript, que cuando devuelvo el RETURN, me crea la estructura anidada.

Puedo, ya como dije anteriormente, sacar solo el [0] o [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYYuD.png), pero, entiendo la lógica FOR, donde por i sería el numero del objeto, pero veo que tengo problemas a la hora de ejecutarlo.

Lo que yo de momento tengo realizado es este:

```
function(){
    var category = document.getElementsByClassName('brdcramb')[0].children[1].innerText;
    if (category != ""){
        return category;
    }else{
        return ("Inicio");
    }
}
```

gracias